# Cant create a clone in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

i  just installed mercurial and tortoise hg and Im a newbie.
I write this commeand at cmd to create a clone: myfile.txt hg clone. But then I cant seee any clone created.And myfile is opened. Can someone help me? Where can I find this created clone?Thanks!

Comment: `hg help clone`, dude! Don't write delirium and expect good results

Comment: You're trying to clone a file, you can't do that, you clone repositories. Here's a mercurial tutorial that might help, you need to read up on the basics of using it first: http://hginit.com/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Like Nanhydrin writes: `hg clone` is to clone repositories.

What is a repository? It is a project folder where you have run `hg init`. Mercurial. You get a repository by taking a project folder and running `hg init`. Then you can add any files in that folder or subfolders and use `hg add` to add them to version control.

Turn a project directory into a repository:

```
cd my-project
hg init  # start a repository in the current directory
# tell Mercurial to start tracking these files
hg add file1 file2 file3 ...  
# commit the files you just added. This is the first commit!
hg commit
```

Clone a repository:

```
hg clone C:/my-mercurial-repos/my-project
[creates a clone of the my-project repository in my-repo]

cd my-project  # Enter the repository
```

You can't 'clone a file', but you can create a copy that Mercurial will also track.

```
hg copy my-file.txt my-file-copy.txt
hg commit
```

For the rest, take Nanhydrin's excellent advice and read http://hginit.com/index.html. It helped me **a lot** when I started using Mercurial.